# Facebook Login URL error using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook

When I try to log in to my application it returns the following error:

> "Can not Load URL: The domain of this URL is not included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The error explains the issue itself. Whatever URL you are using to send the request and expect Facebook to redirect you after user logs in successfully needs to be mentioned in App Domains field in app settings.

[image]